# Flash website preloader for PHP website

Tags: php, html, flash

I want to use a flash preloader for my php website. I have seen some javascript examples; but I want something attractive and cool. So I want use flash preloader which will show the percentage of the website loaded.My website is kinda heavy(with lot of images). It looks bad when the contents load. So I want to show a flash preloader while the site loads. Any help?

Comment: Flash preloader = UI Fail.  I'm navigating away.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a working javascript example it would not be that hard to change it so it calls a flash movie and tell it to update a progressbar or whatever.

Some example code can be found here:
http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashjscommand/

Not sure about the coolness of a flash preloader though. :)

Answer (score 1):

instead of adding some annoying and useless flash-stuff you should think about optimizing your site to load faster so you don't need a loading-indicator (there are some nice artices on this on [code.google.com](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/speed/articles/)) - i don't want to sound offensive, but if a site isn't loaded within a maximum of 2-3 seconds, a lot of users will be annoyed, leave your site and never come back, even if you have the coolest loading-bar ever.

what would be nice to know is waht makes your site so big. the biggest site i can think of is some kind of image-gallery, but even in that case, there is a much easier solution: show thumbnails of your pictures and open the "big" version only on clicking these.